# Configuring python flask folder to WSGI daemon in apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm experimenting with developing python flask app, and would like to configure the app to apache as a daemon, so I wouldn't need to restart apache after every change. The configuration is now like [instructed here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/QuickConfigurationGuide.wiki#Mounting_At_Root_Of_Site%20QuickConfigGuide):

httpd.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess /rapo threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup /rapo
WSGIScriptAlias /rapo /var/www/cgi-bin/pycgi/koe.wsgi
```

koe.wsgi contains just

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/cgi-bin/pycgi")
from koe2 import app as application
```

And in koe2.py there is

```
@app.route('/rapo')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello, World!'
```

that output I can see when I go to the webserver's  /rapo/hello -path, so flask works, but the daemon configuration does not (I still need to restart to see any changes made). Here with [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116481/364931) it seems the key was that the names match, and they do. SW versions: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4.

We don't have any [virtual hosts](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) defined in the httpd.conf, which might be the missing thing, as that worked [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36733012/364931)? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Would this modification to your `httpd.conf` file help?

```
WSGIDaemonProcess api threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /rapo /var/www/cgi-bin/pycgi/koe.wsgi

<Directory rapo>
    WSGIProcessGroup rapo
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried, restarted apache and went to my app via browser. Error log just gives error " No WSGI daemon process called 'rapo' has been configured: /var/www/cgi-bin/pycgi/koe.wsgi"  .

(tried also by replacing 'api' with 'rapo' and  with path <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/pycgi/  , but same thing appears.)

Comment: Here's instructions, I have followed: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: The example should have used ``WSGIProcessGroup api`` not ``WSGIProcessGroup rapo``, but the result would have been the same as was originally used.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not like PHP, source code changes are not reloaded automatically on the next request. In the case of daemon mode, you still need to at least touch the WSGI script file. You can find details about how reloading is handled in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html

At the end of the doc you will find a way of adding code to your application to have source code automatically reloaded no matter what code file is changed, but that should only be done for development and not in production.

If doing development, you are better off using `mod_wsgi-express` from the command line. When you do that, you can use the `--reload-on-changes` option to enable reload on any changes. See:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/05/using-modwsgi-express-as-development.html